How to remove hinge pin?
Struggling to remove hinge pin on an interior door and all my attempts have been futile so far. Hinge has IVES etched on it and it is sticky to touch. Unlike regular hinges, this one has a tiny hole at the bottom which does not let screwdriver to go through nor the tiniest nail I could find. Could it have a bottom cap but the hole is visible to naked eye?
I am willing to buy a tool but without knowing which tool will work, I am little hesitant.
Thank you all!





Have you tried unscrewing the top cap?

There are hinges with pins that can't be easily removed, for security or other reasons. You may  have to unscrew the hinges from the door or frame.

there is no screw on the top cap. pictures attached.
@keshlam but it is an interior bathroom door; should not i be able to remove them?

Your photos don't show the top, but typically a drift pin is used in the hole to drive the hinge pin out.

@HABO i will upload shortly that will be from top angle.

i added two pictures from top view. please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Can you take a measurement of the hole?  The pictures make it look bigger than 1/8, so most smaller(smaller than 4 inch) nails should fit.

Removing the hinge pins to remove the door is usually the fastest.  If plan A does not work, you go to plan B and remove the hinge screws.  Pins 5 seconds, screws 10 seconds.

problem solved! i put a thin thread around the the hinge pin and body and that created a gap using which i could pull the pin using a pliers. i didnt have to touch the bottom at all.

The bottom of the hinge has a hole in it. Try using a metal rod and a hammer through the hole to tap up and remove the pin.

i am unable to find any metal rod that is as thin as the hole. even the thinnest of the nails did not fit in.

There are nails that will fit that hole. You'll need to look around some more. Finish nails are a possible start.

problem solved! i put a thin thread around the the hinge pin and body and that created a gap using which i could pull the pin using a pliers. i didnt have to touch the bottom at all.

That's good news, @biostat ! Post that as an answer and you can checkmark it. Great job!
